# Elasticsearch Transport Client connection

Tags: java, servlets, elasticsearch, servletcontextlistener, elasticsearch-java-api

I’m building a Search Web Application using Servlet which connects to Elasticsearch. I have a question regarding the [Transport](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) module of Elasticsearch. I’m opening the connection to Elasticsearch using the TransportClient in the class that implements ServletContextListener. Below is the code for ElasticsearchServletContextListener class.

```
public class ElasticsearchContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    System.out.println("Starting up!");

    try {
      Client client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(
          new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("IP-address"),9300));
    //Storing the client connection in a static variable
      Parameters.setESclient(client);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    Parameters.getESclient().close();
    System.out.println("Shutting down!");
  }
}
```

Now whenever the user searches for a query it uses the same ‘client’ connection that is initialized in the ServletContextListener class. Can the client connection handle multiple requests at the same time? Or does every user need a separate client connection to query the elasticsearch? Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `Client` instance is able to handle multiple calls and handle multiple threads. And you should have one Client instance only as it's expensive to create one.

Comment: Thank you, Andrei for your reply. Is there a limit to the number of connections it can handle simultaneously?

Comment: Probably a limit at OS level. For example - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-throwing-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-error/31686/7. And, also, ES has some thread pools and some waiting queues for various operations (searches, indexing, bulk indexing etc), but that's at server level. So, in your case I think only the OS level limits are the technical theoretical limits.

Comment: Thank you, Andrei for the explanation.

Comment: Is this officially documented? Can you share a link?

Comment: @DavidSoroko I don't have a link, but trust me :-), this is how it is. And this is how these kind of Java object instances need to be (threadpools, client interfaces, database drivers etc).